# Rails: Shoehorn in a current Devise user on a comment's create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, devise

I've been away from programming for eight months and I am trying to relearn the very very little I knew about developing Rails applications.

I re-did the [Getting Started tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to help myself get back up to speed (visualize a tortoise) before trying to create something original.

I was able to successfully [graft Devise](http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise/) onto the test app as well as [the modification where it can take a username or an e-mail address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).

Now I'm trying to implement user ownership of posts and comments. For Posts, I ran the command:

```
rails g migration AddUserToPosts user:references
```

And similar for Comments. Easy. And adding the current user to a new post was a cinch, just needing one new line in the Posts controller, since I could do it between instantiation and saving:

```
  def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.user = current_user #new
      if @post.save
          redirect_to @post
      else
          render 'new'
      end
  end
```

But for Comments, I'm stumped. Here's what I'm looking at, in the Comments controller:

```
  def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
      #@comment.user = current_user
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

I'd like to shoehorn my user into the comment creation somehow. The commented-out attempt there didn't gum up the works but it didn't do anything either, since the comment was saved to the database in the .create method being called.

So yeah, all that to ask a pretty simple question. Thanks in advance for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your second example, you are calling `create` instead of `new`.

`create` = `new` + `save`

You are saving the comment before assigning the `current_user`.

You can fix this by first using `new` and only saving after assigning `current_user`:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.save
```

Also, in your first example, there's a better way to create a post:

```
@post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
if @post.save
...
```

Comment: I did change to the better (well, one line!) way to create a post. It wasn't making sense to me, but it does if I think about the User having Posts, and that calling "make a new Post" through the User would automatically make the association I need. That's also what's happening for the comments... it makes sense that going through a Post to make a Comment for it would also make the association.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.new` instead of `.create`, then just use a `@comment.save` to manually save the object.

The reason I am suggesting that you switch to `.new` is that it will just create the object in memory. it will not attempt to access the database. If you used `.create` then `.save`, you would be hitting the database twice. Which would be a little inefficient.